# X,Y Width,Height To OpenGL Texture Coord

Tags: c++, math, opengl, textures

If I got a *256 x 256* texture, and a image that's *32 x 32* at *X: 192 Y: 128*, what algerithm would be used to use *glTexCoord2f* to only draw the *32 x 32* image at *X: 192 Y: 128* (to cut out the other parts of the image)?

Here is an example of what I want to do. The blue/red box would be what I'd want to use. But I only want to draw that box, nothing surrounding it, or the whole texture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zefq.png

Comment: So, you want to map that square onto a polygon quad/2 triangles? I'm not sure why you're asking for an algorithm. Do you understand what glTexCoord2f does in general?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
float f = 1.0f/256.0f;
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2f( 192 * f, 128  * f );
    glVertex2f( 192, 128 );

    glTexCoord2f( (192 + 32) * f, 128  * f );
    glVertex2f( 192 + 32, 128 );

    glTexCoord2f( (192 + 32) * f, (128 + 32) * f );
    glVertex2f( 192 + 32, 128 + 32 );

    glTexCoord2f( 192 * f, (128 + 32) * f );
    glVertex2f( 192, 128 + 32 );
glEnd();
```

Remeber that texture coordinates are scaled to the <0,1> interval. Also intermediate mode was deprecated in OpenGL 3.